# ASP: Missing include file

Tags: asp-classic, include

I have a hybrid ASP.NET/ASP Native application that in one asp page uses a include to a .htm page that has hidden fields. I went to edit that page and now when I run the application it throws an execption: Include File Not Found.

I reverted to the last saved version in TFS and the error still remains. Online I have seen some things about absolute path but this is in the same directory as the page thats missing the error and it was working fine.

I tried to check the attributes in Dos and its not READ ONLY.

Has anyone experienced this before and any ideas on how to solve it?

Comment: When you browse directly to the include file, what happens exactly?

Comment: @ShadowWizard - if the file was in c:\myproject\pages\mypage.asp and the include file is the path c:\myproject\pages\includes\includeme.htm my include is <!-- #include file="includes\includeme.htm" -->. If I navigate to the folder its really their.

Comment: Also of important note: it was working before and only after making changes to the include file does it believe it no longer exists

Comment: I mean browse with a browser e.g. `http://localhost/yoursite/includes/includeme.htm` maybe it's permissions issue and browsing like that will shed some light.

Comment: Just found the issue.... the include was placed in notes completely commented out in a page that really did not have reference to that location, that was the one that was failing.

Comment: Cheers, if you think others might find it helpful please post this as new answer. :)

Comment: @ShadowWizard thanks... Yes I was doing just that. There is so little out their on native ASP that everything helps!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Resolved issue:**

I did not realize that ASP will parse comments as real code for certain things. In this case the `<!--include -->` was inside of a comment in a file that would not have had access to that path.

For example:

**ASP Page that really calls the include:**

```
c:\myproject\pages\mypage.asp
```

**Include location:**

```
c:\myproject\pages\includes\includeme.htm
```

**ASP Page that had the notes:**

```
c:\myproject\pages\includes\otherfile.asp
```

The location "`includes\includeme.htm`" was not accessible from otherfile.asp but it was commented out so I assumed it would never try to go their.

```
/*
Some notes....  <!-- #include file="includes\includeme.htm" -->
*/
```

So I removed the comment and it worked perfectly again.

This comment was worth adding to the answer based on how well it explains why what I did worked. Thank You @anonjr

```
#include is a server directive that is processed before anything else is parsed 
- so the server will attempt to retrieve any files you have #include'd and... 
include them.
```

Comment: S/O wont let me accept the answer until tomorrow since I answered my own question.

Comment: Yup, no rush just don't forget to come back. :-)

Comment: `#include` is a server directive that is processed before anything else is parsed - so the server will attempt to retrieve any files you have `#include`'d and... include them.

Comment: Thank you @AnonJr, I wish I could give you a +5 for that explanation!!! So the best I could do is in my answer I quoted you and added your comment to it.